I'm trying to augment images and annotations by rotating, but the classes I set are misaligned afterwards
I have classified the images into A, B, and C. Each has been assigned a class: Acircle for A, Bcircle for B, and Ccircle for C.
Image A has a nearly perfect circular shape.
Image B is close to circular but has some deformations or defects.
Image C is far from circular in shape.enter image description here
Since the data is insufficient, I am performing augmentation. The original images are sized at 1980x1080.
When I rotate the images by 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, and 330 degrees, the JPG files are rotated accurately. However, in the JSON and mask files, the class positions are not correctly aligned, often moving away from the center or ending up in a completely different location compared to the JPG files.
Please help me solve this problem, as ChatGPT was unable to provide a solution.
Below is the corresponding code.
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 이미지 리사이즈 함수
def resize_image(image, target_size=(1024, 1024)):
    """Resizes the image to the target size."""
    return image.resize(target_size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# 좌표 스케일링 함수
def scale_points(points, original_size, new_size):
    """Scales the points to match the resized image."""
    ox, oy = original_size  # 원본 이미지 크기
    nx, ny = new_size  # 새 이미지 크기
    scaled_points = [(x * nx / ox, y * ny / oy) for x, y in points]
    return scaled_points

# 이미지 회전 함수
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    """Rotates the image by the given angle."""
    return image.rotate(angle, expand=True)

# JSON 파일의 점 좌표를 회전하는 함수 (이미지 중심을 기준으로 좌표 변환)
def rotate_points(points, angle, image_size):
    """Rotates points in JSON to match image rotation based on image center."""
    cx, cy = image_size[0] / 2, image_size[1] / 2  # 이미지 중심
    angle_rad = np.radians(angle)
    rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(angle_rad), -np.sin(angle_rad)],
                                [np.sin(angle_rad), np.cos(angle_rad)]])
    rotated_points = []
    for point in points:
        px, py = point
        # 이미지 중심을 기준으로 좌표 변환
        translated_point = np.array([px - cx, py - cy])
        rotated_point = np.dot(rotation_matrix, translated_point) + np.array([cx, cy])
        rotated_points.append(rotated_point.tolist())
    return rotated_points

# 마스크 생성 함수
def create_mask_from_json(json_file, image_size, class_mapping):
    """Creates a mask from a JSON file containing polygon points."""
    mask = np.zeros(image_size, dtype=np.uint8)  # 마스크는 기본적으로 0으로 채워짐 (배경)
    
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for shape in data['shapes']:
        points = np.array(shape['points'], dtype=np.int32)
        label = shape['label']

        # 라벨에 해당하는 클래스 ID로 마스크 채우기
        class_id = class_mapping.get(label, 0)  # label이 class_mapping에 없으면 0으로 설정 (배경)
        
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [points], class_id)

    return mask

# 이미지와 JSON 파일을 회전 및 리사이즈하여 저장하는 함수
def augment_and_transform(image_dir, json_dir, save_image_dir, save_json_dir, save_mask_dir, target_size=(1024, 1024), angles=[30, 60, 90]):
    os.makedirs(save_image_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(save_json_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(save_mask_dir, exist_ok=True)

    image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
    
    for image_file in image_files:
        image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_file)
        json_path = os.path.join(json_dir, image_file.replace('.jpg', '.json'))

        # 이미지 및 JSON 파일 열기
        original_image = Image.open(image_path)
        with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        original_size = original_image.size
        resized_image = resize_image(original_image, target_size)  # 이미지 리사이즈

        for angle in angles:
            rotated_image = rotate_image(resized_image, angle)  # 이미지 회전

            rotated_shapes = []
            for shape in data['shapes']:
                points = shape['points']

                # 좌표 스케일링
                scaled_points = scale_points(points, original_size, target_size)

                # 좌표 회전
                rotated_points = rotate_points(scaled_points, angle, target_size)

                rotated_shapes.append({
                    "label": shape['label'],
                    "points": rotated_points,
                    "shape_type": shape["shape_type"]
                })

            # 회전된 이미지 저장
            rotated_image_name = f"{image_file.replace('.jpg', '')}_rot{angle}.jpg"
            rotated_image.save(os.path.join(save_image_dir, rotated_image_name))

            # 회전된 JSON 파일 저장
            rotated_json_name = f"{image_file.replace('.jpg', '')}_rot{angle}.json"
            rotated_data = data.copy()
            rotated_data['shapes'] = rotated_shapes
            rotated_data['imageWidth'], rotated_data['imageHeight'] = target_size
            with open(os.path.join(save_json_dir, rotated_json_name), 'w') as f:
                json.dump(rotated_data, f, indent=4)

            # 마스크 생성
            mask = create_mask_from_json(os.path.join(save_json_dir, rotated_json_name), target_size, class_mapping)

            # 마스크 저장
            mask_filename = rotated_image_name.replace('.jpg', '_mask.png')
            mask_save_path = os.path.join(save_mask_dir, mask_filename)
            cv2.imwrite(mask_save_path, mask)

            # 시각화
            visualize_mask(rotated_image, mask, rotated_image_name)

# 마스크 시각화 함수
def visualize_mask(image, mask, filename):
    """Displays the original image and corresponding mask."""
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

    # 원본 이미지 시각화
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title(f"Original Image: {filename}")
    plt.axis('off')

    # 마스크 시각화
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(mask, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5)
    plt.title(f"Generated Mask: {filename}")
    plt.axis('off')

    plt.show()

# 클래스 ID 매핑 (라벨을 클래스 ID로 변환)
class_mapping = {
    'Acircle': 1,
    'Bcircle': 2,
    'Ccircle': 3
}

# 경로 설정
train_image_dir = 'C:/New/resize_train_jpg'
train_json_dir = 'C:/New/resize_train_json'
save_image_dir = 'C:/New/augmented_train_jpg'
save_json_dir = 'C:/New/augmented_train_json'
save_mask_dir = 'C:/New/augmented_train_mask'

# 각도 설정 (30도씩 회전)
angles = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330]

# 증강 및 변환 실행
augment_and_transform(train_image_dir, train_json_dir, save_image_dir, save_json_dir, save_mask_dir, angles=angles)

enter image description here
Worked on augmentation code with ChatGPT for 7 days

carefully check your operations. a rotation is always around the origin. when you define some other point to be the origin, by subtracting it, you'll have to add it back after the rotation. also don't trust PIL to do what you expect. it probably does something slightly different.

Okay, I'll think about it carefully like you said. Do you have any more advice for me?
